# Set theory: infinite cardinal number proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $a$ be a cardinal number and let $b$ be an infinite cardinal number. Prove that if $1 < a$ and $a=a^{b}$, then $b < a$.

My attempt is to prove by contradiction.

Suppose that $a \leq b$. Then, since $b$ is infinite, $a^{b}=2^{b}=a$. I am stuck here. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: If it is by contradiction then you must assume $\;a\color{red}\le b\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio yes my mistake i have edited it..

Comment: $a^b \ge 2^b > b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\;a\le b\;$ , then

$$a\stackrel{\text{given}}=a^b\ge a^a\implies a\ge a^a\ge 2^a>a\implies\text{contradiction}$$